# Removing only the first child element and keeping the second with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, recursion, selector, removechild

Looked around and couldn't find an answer to this, but apologies if it's been asked before.

I'm looking to replace one DIV with another of the same kind, animating the new one in, then removing the first DIV, allowing the new DIV to take the removed DIV's place.  After creating and appending the new DIV, the HTML code looks like this (minus the comments):

```
<div class="className">Inner HTML</div> <!-- original "className" div -->
<div class="className">Inner HTML</div> <!-- appended "className" div -->
```

I've tried several methods, the most recent being:

```
$(".className:eq(0)").remove();
```

and

```
$(".className:eq(0)").html() = $(".className:eq(1)").html();
$(".className:eq(1)").remove();
```

The first method removes all "className" elements, most likely due to the [0] element referring to the array as a whole.  The second method eliminates the second element, not the first.

It would be simple enough to animate the new element in and leave things as they are, but I want avoid having a build-up of "className" elements in the DOM, as the solution needs to be recursive, allowing the "className" div to be replaced as many times as necessary.

Comment: Wait a minute, it is `bodyDiv` or `className` ? Choose one :) Also you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example to let us play with.

Comment: I had fixed the variable names in the post (className was correct), but I've half-solved it at this point - has to do with the HTML and BODY tags, and dual processing of things.  I'm going to have the mods pull down the question entirely at this point, as the entire scope has changed.  I'm new to this site, so I'll read up on things and come back when I'm a little better prepared.  Apologies to everyone for the confusion, but thank you all very much for your help and suggestions, all of which seemed spot-on.

Comment: Solved it, actually - still going to have the mods pull it down, though, as it has nothing to do with the original question. :p  Sorry again for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

```
$(".className:first-child").remove();
```

If at max only two (the old and the new) `className` can be neighbours, you can select the second, then step back to the first.

```
$(".className + .className").prev().remove();
```

Steal some ideas from:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: The .prev().remove() solution seems to work - thanks!  However, the "first-child" solution wipes out all of the elements, similar to the eq(0) approach.  Been all over the selectors page before, but will chek out the traversing section as well.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't those `.classNames` wrapped into another div accidentally? Like `<div><div class="classNames">...</div></div>` ? `:first-child` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/d2xDy/

Comment: Actually, they are - sorry about that.  In this case, they're directly under the BODY tag, but they are intended to be inside another DIV.  I've edited the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple use **[`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith)**

```
$(".className:first-child").replaceWith('<div class="className">Inner HTML</div>');
```

`.replaceWith` will replace previous `classsName` with new one, in that case you don't need `.append()` and `.remove()`.

**OR**

```
$(".className:first").remove();
```

#### According to comment

I think you're trying something like following:

```
$('<div class="className">New Div</div>').appendTo('#target').animate({
    width: 120,
    height: 120
}, 1500, function() {
    $('div.className:first').remove();
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/519/)**

Comment: The thing is, I need to create the new DIV then animate it in, which is why I want to create, append() and animate() in the new div, then remove() the old one.  It looks like replaceWith() switches out the contents, which won't allow for animation.

Comment: @user1489258 please check my demo, I think this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method

```
 $(".className").first().remove();
```

If you never want to delete ALL the objects, you can safeguard by checking the length of the resultset first:

```
   if($(".className").length > 1) {
          $('className").first().remove();
   }
```

Comment: This produces results similar to the eq(0) remove() approach, wiping out all of the elements.

Comment: No it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/U6cQg/ 

Unless you're calling it recursively of course - once it's removed one element, leaving one, the next time called it will remove that one too.

Comment: Post the rest of your code - reading your comments above - you're almost certainly called the function repeatedly.